# Prove that $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $A = [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Prove that $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $A = [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$

To my knowledge I need to use Fubini's theorem. But this doesn't work because the integration would be 0. Can anyone give me some hints? Many thanks

Comment: If one uses polar coordinates, it seems that $f$ is integrable over any compact set: $f(r\cos u,r \sin u)=\cos u \sin u$.

Comment: The function is bounded and continuous on $[-1,1]^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, so it ought to be all kinds of integrable there. And adding a single point should not matter for the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: The question statement is probably a typo. If the denominator is squared, this is not integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one uses polar coordinates, it seems that, as is any **trigonometric polynomial**, $f$ is integrable over any compact set: $$f(x,y)=f(r\cos u,r \sin u)=\cos u \sin u.$$